# Ударение в фамилии Яминова

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия

Я учитель, правда не русского языка, а математики, и у меня есть ученица. Её фамилия - ЯмИнова, я, произнося ее фамилию ставлю ударение на И, а она впадает в истерику и кричит, что она Яминова, ударение на Я, не могу я так произносить, у меня язык сводит. А как правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Так, как принято в семье.

Answer (score 2):

Я присоединяюсь к ответу Алена7.

Плохо, что ученица кричит в разговоре с учительницей, но тут она права по сути.
В русском языке, как, впрочем, и в большинстве других, на имена собственные нет единых правил. Для фамилии - за редчайшими исключениями - считается правильным то и только то ударение, на котором настаивает её носитель.

Вам совет: произносите примерно как "Маминова" с заменой первого звука. 
Тут вам язык не сведет?

//===================

А фамилия-то оказалось интересной. 
Конечно же, к яме-канаве, как, может быть, полагает ученица, никакого отношения не имеет.
Я был "на все что" уверен, что она образована от тюркского имени Ямин (идущий первым - прям тезка Гайдара); ударение, естественно, на втором слоге, поэтому учительницу можно в чем-то понять. 
Оказывается, не всё так просто. Вот попалась версия, что это от "яма" - почтовой станции, и не только станции, от яма образованы "ямской", "ямщик" и проч. Тогда ударение на Я объяснимо. Другое дело, что я никогда не сталкивался со словом "ямин" в отношении чего-то ямского, ямщицкого, будь то притяжательное прилагательное или субстантив.

//===================

Лирическое отступление или История о том, как не смогли договориться три еврея.
В моей семье дед, отец, дядя и я произносили фамилию по-разному.
Ну то есть слога-то два, а "варианта" три. 
Я в школьные годы использовал вариант, принятый всеми известными мне однофамильцами, с ударением на первом слоге. С возрастом пришлось переучиться, знакомые отца замучили. Отец - употреблял тот вариант, который слышал от деда и его сослуживцев. Дядя моложе отца и с дедовыми сослуживцами контачил во взрослом возрасте мало. Поэтому с ударением проблем не испытывал.
Самое интересное - дед. Как настоящий еврей(,) он на все вопросы отвечал "И ты тоже прав". Все дело в том, что в бытность его курсантом какой-то тогдашний прапорщик (привычных званий тогда не было) заявил, что правильно не так, а эдак. Дед уже тогда проявил понимание военной доктрины молодого советского государства - и козырнул. Не переучиваться же ему, когда он стал генералом. Ровно семьдесят лет назад, под Сталинградом. Войну начинал майором... Целых полгода был самым молодым генералом в войсках ПВО.

ЗЫ Фамилия деда - Райнин. Мой ник - behemothus. Прошу не смешивать.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с тем, что считается правильным  то произношение, на котором настаивает её носитель. В фамилии "Яминова" ударение не может падать, наверное, только на последний слог. Хотя... сколько гласных, столько может быть и вариантов.